# Tool for rest webservice parameterized load test

Tags: testing, automated-tests, stress-testing

I have a set of rest webservices in java, I need a tool that allows to load test them using parameters (i use windows operating system and Java or .net). I need to call 1 webservice 100 times simultaneously with different parameters.
This can be done just calling the method that is the core of the webservice, so basically I need to run a unit test many times concurrently with different parameters
Can you suggest any SIMPLE tool?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/Load-Testing/loadtest-execution.html)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has a load testing component. I would recommend recording a "unit test" using [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and exporting as a Visual Studio webtest.

Visual studio will allow you to plug in parameter values from a spreadsheet, text file or database.

The downside is the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition is required for this, which is not cheap.
Otherwise the old [WCat](http://www.iis.net/community/Performance) may do the trick.

You could still record the exact details of the transaction using Fiddler and convert to tests using JMeter to do the load test bit.

Answer (score 0):

Web Performance Load Tester. It is not specifically designed for web services, but works pretty well with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the chrome extension "DHC Client" for testing web service. It provide a very good interface and you can also check it with test and image too. Here is link:-

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en
```

It also store the variable value for the next time and you can also store the cases and value for future reference.